# Django M2M: get objects containing all elements of array

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm trying to solve the problem of getting objects using many-to-many relation. The issue is following:

I have an array of selected filters, that is, let's say, **[red, rounded]**. Then I have a model of product that contains a lot of filters' values like: **red, blue, rounded, blank, big, small**

I'm aimed at getting products that are both **red** and **rounded**

When I'm using `__in=[array]` it obviously leads to getting those products which are red along with those are rounded.

The only working solution for me was using:

```
products.objects.filter(fil=red).filter(fil=rounded).all()
```

But I wonder if there is any method of not using a lot of `filter()` since the amount needed is unpredictable (e.g. user can pick [red, blue, white, rounded].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a custom query using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
# Build the query for selected terms
custom_query = None
for term in selected_terms:
    query_for_term = Q(fil=term)
    # Keep and'ing(&) terms
    custom_query = custom_query & query_for_term if custom_query else query_for_term

# Then filter using the query
products.objects.filter(custom_query)
```